# Why image blurry after resize in IE but Chrome is much better?

Tags: image, google-chrome, internet-explorer

[image: Same image resize in IE and Chrome]

Drag and Drop any image to IE and Chrome, and try resize the browsers' window size, you will find the image in IE is blurry but Chrome is better, why ?